# JavaMail intermittently throws FolderClosedExcpetion on IMAPMessage.loadEnvelope()

Tags: java, imap, jakarta-mail

I have a java service that consumes emails from a Postfix mail server. It's handling about 1 email per second and processes the content of the emails.

However, very intermittently I get this exception:

```
javax.mail.FolderClosedException : * BYE [ALERT] Fatal error: Invalid argument - javax.mail.FolderClosedException: * BYE [ALERT] Fatal error: Invalid argument
        at com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPMessage.loadEnvelope(IMAPMessage.java:1256)
        at com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPMessage.getSubject(IMAPMessage.java:335)
        at com.mailparser.data.MessageParser.parse(MessageParser.java:33)
```

If I exit the process and restart it again it will always throw the same exception on the same messages and thus they get stuck in the inbox.

here's a code snippet of where it's failing:

```
if (!message.getFolder().isOpen()) {
    message.getFolder().open(Folder.READ_WRITE);
    Logger.log("Tried to reopen folder"); //This is never hit
}
ReceivedEmail incomingMessage = new ReceivedEmail();
try {
    incomingMessage.setSubject(message.getSubject()); // Exception happens here
    [...]
} catch {
    catch (FolderClosedException ex) {
        message.getFolder().open(Folder.READ_WRITE); 
        Logger.log("Reopened", LogType.debug);
        return null;
    }
}
```

As you can see I'm checking to see if the folder is open before I try to get the subject, so I suspect that something else is causing this failure. Once it has thrown the expections for the stuck messages it carries on successfully using exactly the same folder and connection.

Does anyone have any idea on this?

Thanks!

Edit:

Debug info as requested by Bill:

```
   DEBUG IMAP: LOGIN command trace suppressed
    DEBUG IMAP: LOGIN command result: A0 OK LOGIN Ok.
    A1 CAPABILITY
    * CAPABILITY IMAP4rev1 UIDPLUS CHILDREN NAMESPACE THREAD=ORDEREDSUBJECT THREAD=REFERENCES SORT QUOTA IDLE ACL ACL2=UNION
    A1 OK CAPABILITY completed
    A2 LIST INBOX ""
    * LIST (\Marked \HasChildren) "." ""
    A2 OK LIST completed
    A3 LIST "" INBOX.TEST
    * LIST (\HasChildren) "." "INBOX.TEST"
    A3 OK LIST completed
    DEBUG: connection available -- size: 1
    A4 SELECT INBOX.TEST
    * FLAGS (\Draft \Answered \Flagged \Deleted \Seen \Recent)
    * OK [PERMANENTFLAGS (\* \Draft \Answered \Flagged \Deleted \Seen)] Limited
    * 1 EXISTS
    * 0 RECENT
    * OK [UIDVALIDITY 1351176418] Ok
    * OK [MYRIGHTS "acdilrsw"] ACL
    A4 OK [READ-WRITE] Ok

DEBUG IMAP: IMAPProtocol noop
A7 NOOP
A7 OK NOOP completed
A8 FETCH 1 (FLAGS)
* 1 FETCH (FLAGS (\Answered \Seen))
A8 OK FETCH completed.
A9 FETCH 1 (ENVELOPE INTERNALDATE RFC822.SIZE)
* BYE [ALERT] Fatal error: Invalid argument
```

Comment: And by intermittent I mean it happens on average to one per 5000 emails

Comment: It *looks* like a bug in the library or server.  You may need to trace the protocol to see what it's doing and which messages exactly cause the error.

Comment: The server is complaining that some command argument value is **so** bad that it has to break the connection, but it won't bother telling you what exactly it's complaining about.  To find out, you'll need to look at the protocol trace (see the JavaMail FAQ).  Post the trace here and we can help you figure out whether there's something wrong with the library or the client (unlikely) or whether the server is buggy (possibly).  Depending on the exact error, there may be a way to work around it in your application.

Comment: Thanks Bill. Please see my edit. Let me know if this is not what you're after

Comment: I guess its a server bug. Can you post vendor and version of the server?